# Como sacaria el ganador de los candidatos?

Tags: java, array

No he sabido como sacar el ganador directamente por el nombre, asi que lo que he hecho ha sido sacar por el mas alto porcentaje, pero al correrlo me salen todos como ganadores. Esto es lo que he estado intentando:
Se supone que lo tengo que sacar de los arreglos conforme a los votos o al porcentaje de los votos 
pero no he podidio. Ya he intentado varias otras formas y todas o me salen igual o me salen una sola no ganador y las demas ganador, o simplemente no me aparece la de no ganador.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner miScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numerocandidatos; 

    System.out.println("¿Cuantos candidatos hay inscritos?");
    numerocandidatos = Integer.parseInt(miScanner.nextLine());

    String[] nombrecandidatos = new String[numerocandidatos];
    for(int i = 0; i<nombrecandidatos.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Porfavor dame un nombre de los candidatos");
        nombrecandidatos[i] = miScanner.nextLine();
    }

    int[] votos = new int[numerocandidatos];
    for(int i = 0; i<votos.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Porfavor deme el numero de votos por candidato en el mismo orden");
        votos[i] = Integer.parseInt(miScanner.nextLine());
    }

    int suma = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<votos.length; i++){ 
       suma += votos[i];
    }

    double[] porcentaje = new double[numerocandidatos];
    for(int i = 0; i<porcentaje.length; i++){
        porcentaje[i] = (votos[i] * 100) / suma;

        System.out.println("Candidatos: " + nombrecandidatos[i] + " Votos: " + votos[i] + " Porcentaje: " + porcentaje[i] + "%");
    }
    int mayor = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<porcentaje.length; i++){
            if (porcentaje[i]>mayor){
                System.out.println(nombrecandidatos[i] + " Ganador");

            } else {
                System.out.println(nombrecandidatos[i] + " No gano");
            }

        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres mostrar cuál tiene mayor número de votos. Pero ese `for` del final no hace lo que esperas para empezar porque nunca das valor a `mayor`, con lo que tiene siempre valor `0` y todos van a ser mayores que `0`.

Tienes que recorrer todos guardándote el valor mayor y al final del bucle, sabrás cual es el mayor. Algo como esto:

```
double mayor = porcentaje[0]; //Guardamos como mayor el primero.
String nombreMayor = nombreCandidatos[0];
//El bucle empieza en 1 porque el primero ya lo tenemos.
for( int i = 1; i < numerocandidatos; i++) {

    if( porcentaje[i] > mayor) {
        //Si el actual es mayor, lo guardamos como mayor.
        mayor = porcentaje[i];
        nombreMayor = nombreCandidatos[i];
    }
}
//en mayor tienes el valor mayor.
System.out.println( "El ganador es " + nombreMayor);
```